# Check if URL is reachable from the current host

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

I'm trying to check if a given URL if reachable from my current host.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    url1 = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/GuitareClassique5.png/150px-GuitareClassique5.png";
    urlYoutube = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/F2AitTPI5U0";
    url3 = "https://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4";
    brokenUrl = "http://www.example.com/images/1.png";  


    $.ajax({
     url: url3,
     type: "HEAD",
     fail: function () { alert("Error triggered "); },
     success: function () { alert("Success triggered"); }
    }); 


});
```

So my problem is that **url1** is the only one who gives me the correct answer.
**urlYoutube**, **url3**, and **brokenUrl** returns a CORS error : **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.**

So I've looking back and forth for a solution on the internet, and the solution that I came up with is to add **dataType: "jsonp"** on the ajax request parameters, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

Is there any other solution/plugin to check if an URL is reachable from my host ?

Comment: If you get a CORS error, that means the URL cannot be used via `$.ajax()`, so it means the answer is "not reachable".

Comment: @Pointy there's a lot of difference between "not reachable" and "not usable due to CORS security constraints"

Comment: @Alnitak true, though to me the very idea of determining network connectivity is shaky. The question is of course not clear, as the goal isn't stated.

Comment: @Pointy I come from a network engineering background where "not reachable" has a pretty unambiguous meaning ;)

Comment: I defer to your expertise, but as a simple programmer I've learned to assume that at any point in time the network may completely disappear, only to reappear when the "network offline" error handler is invoked :)

Comment: @Pointy actually, from a network perspective I'd argue that a CORS error indicates that the remote site *is* reachable, since the error depends on making a successful connection but then not getting the expected CORS header in the response.

Comment: @Alnitak sure, I agree; I was guessing that the OP wanted to actually get content from the target, but who knows?

Answer (score 1):

Try using an `Image` element, setting its `.src` property and then catching `.onerror` events.

Images aren't subject to the same CORS restrictions as `XMLHttpRequest` objects.

You may need to put a random suffix (e.g. `#<timestamp>`) on the image URL to ensure that your app isn't fooled by caching.

Answer (score -1):

As an addition to Alnitak's answer you can in the ajax turn of caching

```
$.ajax({ cache: false,...});
```

this will give same result as putting a random suffix on the url

Comment: no, was only an, in my opinion, easier way than adding suffix on the url :)